# How to add label on a piechart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

[image]

I want to add the label above every pie .i.e yellow = east ;blue=west ....

data .tsv

```
  region    fruit   count
East    Apples  53245
West    Apples  28479
South   Apples  19697
North   Apples  24037
Central Apples  40245
East    Oranges 200
South   Oranges 200
Central Oranges 200
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

input {
  margin: 0 7px;
}

</style>
<form></form>
<br><br><br><br>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;


var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.count; })
    .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - 100)
    .outerRadius(radius - 20);



var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.selectAll("path");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  var regionsByFruit = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.fruit; })
      .entries(data)
      .reverse();

  var label = d3.select("form").selectAll("label")
      .data(regionsByFruit)
    .enter().append("label");

  label.append("input")
      .attr("type", "radio")
      .attr("name", "fruit")
      .attr("value", function(d) { return d.key; })
      .on("change", change)
    .filter(function(d, i) { return !i; })
      .each(change)
      .property("checked", true);

  label.append("span")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });

  function change(region) {
    var data0 = path.data(),
        data1 = pie(region.values);

    path = path.data(data1, key);

    path.enter().append("path")
        .each(function(d, i) { this._current = findNeighborArc(i, data0, data1, key) || d; })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.region); })
      .append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.data.region; });

    path.exit()
        .datum(function(d, i) { return findNeighborArc(i, data1, data0, key) || d; })
      .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween)
        .remove();

    path.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween);
  }
});

function key(d) {
  return d.data.region;
}

function type(d) {
  d.count = +d.count;
  return d;
}

function findNeighborArc(i, data0, data1, key) {
  var d;
  return (d = findPreceding(i, data0, data1, key)) ? {startAngle: d.endAngle, endAngle: d.endAngle}
      : (d = findFollowing(i, data0, data1, key)) ? {startAngle: d.startAngle, endAngle: d.startAngle}
      : null;
}

// Find the element in data0 that joins the highest preceding element in data1.
function findPreceding(i, data0, data1, key) {
  var m = data0.length;
  while (--i >= 0) {
    var k = key(data1[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
      if (key(data0[j]) === k) return data0[j];
    }
  }
}

// Find the element in data0 that joins the lowest following element in data1.
function findFollowing(i, data0, data1, key) {
  var n = data1.length, m = data0.length;
  while (++i < n) {
    var k = key(data1[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
      if (key(data0[j]) === k) return data0[j];
    }
  }
}

function arcTween(d) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) { return arc(i(t)); };
}

</script>
```

How should I modify the above referenced codes?

I tried to add somethings like

```
    arc.append("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")"; })
  .attr("dy", "0.35em")
  .text(function(d) { return data.region; });
```

But obviously , it doesn't work

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: May be this can help http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/2295263

Comment: no  , this sample is not that dynamic as mine .And I don;t want hard code in same file